# Media query that targets 1024px but displays differently for desktop and tablet? Possible?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using standard media queries to target various breakpoints in pixels (eg. @media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px)) but I have been asked that a different layout show up for desktops at 1024px and a different one for tablets at the same 1024px width.

Is this even possible? As far as I'm aware it isn't, but I thought I'd get advice on here to make sure.

Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like you would need to detect what device you are and then serve the appropriate css

Comment: What could you possibly want different for 2 devices with the same viewport sizes?  If the answer is "I want to optimize for touch", then checking the dimensions of the viewport is the wrong approach (related:  http://www.stucox.com/blog/the-good-and-bad-of-level-4-media-queries/).

Comment: @cimmanon It doesn't sound unreasonable to me.  If he is providing a radically different visual style for tablets and mobile phones compared to the desktop version, then wouldn't he want to provide the standard desktop view for desktops specifically?  I know plenty of people who have not adopted new technology and still run 17inch CRT's with a resolution of 1024x768, uses who shouldn't necessarily see a tablet view of the site.

Comment: It depends why you want to change css.  Do you only care about whether the device supports touch, or are you targeting specific browsers? (ipad-safari, android-chrome, android-dolphin, etc)

Comment: thanks for the comments, guys. no real clear reason is given, except that tablets should look different to desktop (hiding the main navigation bar etc.)

i haven't seen this done before and my research hasn't turned anything up so was curious about it and whether or not it's possible.

Comment: @Michael What is "tablet view"?  Media query attributes pertaining to the dimensions of the device can only be used to accurately optimize a design for a particular viewport size.  They cannot be used to accurately determine the difference between "phone", "tablet", "desktop", or "James Bond's wristwatch" since these items have overlapping viewport sizes.

Comment: You need to be more specific, an ipad is obviously a tablet, does a windows touch desktop count as a tablet.  Basically you can check user agent and/or check if there is touch support on the device.

Comment: @cimmanon I meant tablet view as a general term for some given design for what OP's design should look like on a tablet. I realize that viewport sizes overlap, which is exactly what my point was tying into.  Some screen of a 17" CRT at 1024px probably shouldn't see the same site as what the OP wants to show as their "tablet view" or tablet design.  My example above entails a situation where the viewport sizes are the same, but depending on OP's design, probably wants to deliver a completely different experience for the person on a 17" monitor.  That doesnt seem unreasonable to me.

Comment: @Michael Other than touch vs. pointer considerations, why shouldn't they see the same thing?  Optimizing a design for viewport is optimizing for viewport, regardless of device involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do what you want in pure [media query CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).  Basically, you can target tablet beyond just the screen size:

**Touch Support**

CSS4 gives media queries a new touch option.  Since this isn't supported very widely yet you can use Modernizr.  It will add a class to the root html of "touch" or "no-touch".  You can then use that to target touch devices.  Example:

```
html.touch .someToolbar {display: none;}  //hides toolbar on touch devices
```

**User Agent**

Using javascript detect the user agent and load the appropriate css or just make the style changes if they're small

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i)) { /* do tablet/mobile specific things */}
```

**Resolution**

If you want to target a [specific screen size](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html).  For example, I want anyone running 1024 with 11inch or smaller screen

```
@media 
    only screen and (oriantation: landscape) and (device-width: 1024px) and ( min-resolution: 116dpi),
    only screen and (oriantation: portrait) and (device-height: 1024px) and ( min-resolution: 116dpi), {
   //targets specifically 1024 width with screen size 10 inch or smaller
}
```

NOTE - I have not used the resolution method, testing needed.

Comment: I think I will try the user agent method as I'm not sure how future-proof touch is (desktops may have that functionality at some point!)

the resolution method also looks good and I am trying to figure out browser compatbility for it. also concerned about what will happen if screen sizes for handhelds/tablets become larger in the future.

basically, I want something future-proof but realize options are limited at the moment.

Comment: It just depends on what you mean by handheld/tablet.  Is an android "laptop" what?  is a windows 8 laptop with a detachable top a tablet when it gets unhooked?  Honestly you should care less about the tablet/handhelt "classification" and more about what you want the user experience to be.  For me, that usually changes depending on screen size and whether they have touch enabled.

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question: Yes it is possible. Checkout Bootstrap 3. It's all ready to go with model, tablet and desktop media queries already baked in. No need for any customization unless you want to.

Comment: But does it differentiate between a desktop browser on a 1024px monitor and a tablet on a 1024px viewport? That's the OP's question...If so, how?

Comment: bootstrap responsive is only differentiated by screen size, not by user agent.

Comment: When your browser connects to a website, it includes a User-Agent field in its HTTP header. The contents of the user agent field vary from browser to browser. Each browser has its own, distinctive user agent. The web server can use this information to serve different web pages to different web browsers and different operating systems.